# Removing external lua files and sprite Sheets from memory in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

My application has lot of sprite sheets and their respective lua files.I have used director class to switch between different screens and I have also used `spriteSheet:dispose()` statement during screen transition. Even though my application is crashing in the iPad. I have cancelled all the timers and transitions, removed all Run time listeners, used `collectgarbage()` at the enterFrame event of run time. Yet my application is crashing. Is it because of external files or any other problem? Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information:

- it is also crashing in the simulator or only on the Ipad ?
- if it is crashing in the simulator, what is the lua error in the console ?
- did you close the other apps on the iPad, if you have too many there is not enough memory for your app
- did you add a listener for low memory, this will tell you whether the problem is memory or not:

```
local function handleLowMemory( event )
  native.showAlert( "Low Memory!",  "Please consider closing other applications.." , { "OK" }  );
end
```

Runtime:addEventListener( "memoryWarning", handleLowMemory )

Comment: Thanks tomdemuyt . It is not crashing in the simulator.In the simulator I hav not encountered any problem even if I run it for whole one day.The problem is only in the iPad.It is not running even for ten minutes.

Comment: Okay, but did you add the low memory handler, does it trigger ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check one of your sprite image size. If the image size is greater than double resolution of retina size then the app will crash.